# Change HTML5 <button>'s formaction dynamically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with different multiple submit buttons that perform separate actions.

One of these buttons is part of a bootstrap modal that adds a quantity field. When I press this button I would like it to add the value of the quantity field as a url parameter. For example a user enters 25 in the quantity text field and clicks submit, they should POST the form data to the page www.example.com/folder/?quantity=25.

Unfortunately I am a complete novice to javascript and jquery, so I tried to modify an answer to someone else's question on how to change a form's action to work on my button.

Right now my modal and submit button are working, but the button's formaction is not being changed. I have also tried changing the form's action using the script below and removing the action from the button, but with no success.

Any assistance would be much appreciated. Additionally, I do not care about not supporting older browsers. If just firefox and chrome support it, that is good enough for me.

```
<div class="modal fade bs-order-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
<div class="modal-content">
<input type='text' name='quantity' id="quatity">
<li><button name='btn-add' id='btn-add' type="submit" form="id-details" formaction="/inventory/order/" class="btn btn-info">Add to Order List</button></li>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/docs.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
   $('#btn-add').submit(function(){
     var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
     $(this).attr('formaction', "/inventory/order/?quantity=" + quatity);
   });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is the button doesn't have a submit event - the form does. What you want to do is modify the click event of the button instead. Also for safety I prefer to use `$(document).ready()` when attaching the event:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('#btn-add').on('click', function () {
            var quantity = $('#quatity').val(); // Your ID on the "quantity" input is missing an "n"
            $(this).attr('formaction', "/inventory/order/?quantity=?quantity=" + quantity);
        });
    });
```

Finally, you may want to add some basic validation to make sure the value in the textbox isn't empty or alphanumeric.